# Unable to run jest test case

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I have written a small test case to test a ThankYouPage component which looks like below

```
import ToggleDisplay from 'react-toggle-display';
import styles from '../styles.css';

function ThankYouPage(props) {
  return (
    <ToggleDisplay show={props.show}>
      <div className={styles.thankyouText}> Thank you!</div>
      <div className={styles.helpText}>
        The more you thanks, the better.
      </div>
    </ToggleDisplay>
  );
}

export default ThankYouPage;
```

Following is the test case in jest -

```
import React from 'react';
import ThankYouPage from './components/thank-you-page';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';


describe('<ThankYouPage />', () => {
  it('renders 1 ThankYouPage component', () => {
    const component = shallow(<ThankYouPage show=true />);
    expect(component).toHaveLength(1);
  });
});
```

Following is the trace on console I get after running `npm test`

```
> myreactapp@1.0.0 test /Users/rahul/myreactapp
> jest

 FAIL  tests/thank-you-page.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    /Users/cominventor/myreactapp/tests/thank-you-page.test.js: Unexpected token (8:30)
         6 | describe('<ThankYouPage />', () => {
         7 |   it('renders 1 ThankYouPage component', () => {
      >  8 |     const component = shallow(<ThankYouPage show=true />);
           |                               ^
         9 |     expect(component).toHaveLength(1);
        10 |   });
        11 | });
```

Am I missing a dependency to interpret jsx within shallow? Following is how my deps look like

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "^22.4.3",
    "oc-template-react-compiler": "5.0.2",
    "prettier": "^1.10.2",
    "prettier-eslint": "^8.8.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "jest": "^22.4.3",
    "jsdom": "^11.10.0",
    "querystring": "^0.2.0",
    "react-cookie": "^2.1.4",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.4",
    "react-toggle-display": "^2.2.0"
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jest not preprocessing my JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33958757/jest-not-preprocessing-my-jsx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try installing

`npm i --save-dev enzyme enzyme-adapter-react-16`

Add transform-class-properties to .babelrc file like below -

```
"plugins": [
    "transform-class-properties"
  ]
```

Add following to top level in package.json

```
"jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css)$": "jest-css-modules"
    }
```

Following unit test should then work fine.

```
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme, { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import ThankYouPage from './components/thank-you-page';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('<ThankYouPage />', () => {
  it('renders 1 ThankYouPage component', () => {
    const component = shallow(<ThankYouPage show=true />);
    expect(component).toHaveLength(1);
  });
});
```

Comment: Enzyme.configure didn't work for me but just configure did. Also, I had to make changes to babelrc using the thread suggested by Håken Lid. What remains is to get jest process `import styles from '../styles.css';` . I tried installing jest-css-modules but seems I need some babel setting to get it work

Comment: what solved the css problem was including jest-css-modules

Comment: I would suggest you to complete the answer by including the above. I think without the css suggestion, the answer would not be complete.

Comment: if it is a problem with css you have to include these lines in package.json "jest": {
    "transform": {
      ".*": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest"
    },
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|scss)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-css-modules"
    }
  }

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    import * as React from 'react';
    import * as Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
    import {shallow, configure} from 'enzyme';
    import ThankYouPage from './components/thank-you-page';

   configure({adapter: new Adapter()});

   describe('my test', () => {
     ...
     ...
   });
```

install `enzyme-adapter-react-16` package from npm.

Comment: also, based on my experience with other languages, the idea of import * as React looks bit bad. I think we should only import what's needed. Watsay?

Answer (score 0):

You are importing enzyme in wrong way ( not relative path ), try `import { shallow } from 'enzyme';`

Comment: thanks @krystian-sztadhaus. that was helpful but it didn't fix the issue :(