# Make Jest ignore the .less import when testing

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs

## Testing Components

I am trying to run some very simple tests on react components with Jest. I am running into problems because of this line at the top of my component file

```
import {} from './style.less';
```

The import here doesn't need to be tested and would ideally be ignored from the test.

## Result of [npm test]

When the test is run via `npm test` I get the response

> FAIL  **tests**/app_test.js ● Runtime Error SyntaxError: Unexpected
>   token { in file 'client/components/app/style.less'.
>
> Make sure your preprocessor is set up correctly and ensure your
>   'preprocessorIgnorePatterns' configuration is correct:
>   http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html#preprocessorignorepatterns-array-string
>   If you are currently setting up Jest or modifying your preprocessor,
>   try `jest --no-cache`. Preprocessor: node_modules/jest-css-modules.
>   Jest tried to the execute the following preprocessed code: //some .less code

But if I comment out the less import line my test runs correctly.

## Question

How can I get jest to skip over this line of code or ignore this import?

Comment: Check this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/36137733/2765745
Worked for me.

Answer (score 26):

The only way I could get jest to ignore less files for me, other than manually mocking the .less file at the top of the test e.g.

```
jest.mock("../../src/styles.less", () => jest.fn());
```

Was to add the following to the package.json:

```
"jest": {
 "moduleNameMapper": {
  ".*\\.less$": "<rootDir>/pathToDummyFile/dummy.js"
  }
 },
```

Whenever your code tries to import a less file it will instead redirect the import to fetch an empty dummy file, which will avoid the unexpected token error you experienced.

Comment: This worked. Special mention of `<rootDir>` react document states that if we are pointing to a file then `<rootDir>` should be used which resolves to the absolute path to the `dummy.js` file. I put this configuration into my `jest.config.js` file.

Comment: This is a correct answer in my opinion, @joe-lloyd please consider marking it appropriately if you're satisfied.

Answer (score 14):

If you still have this issue, try to add the following config to your `jest.config.json` file:

```
"transform": {
  "^.+\\.(css|less)$": "./styleMock.js"
}
```

Here, in your `styleMock.js` you're creating a [transformer](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#transform-object-string-string) which will transform your `.less` files like this:

```
module.exports = {
  process() {
    return ''
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not work. by doing this, Jest complains about the import statements in React components. ```import App from '../App'
    ^^^^^^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token import```

Comment: You will also need to add `"^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",` so that normal JS files are transformed correctly.

Answer (score 9):

A little late to the party but maybe this will help someone today. Use [jest-transform-stub](https://github.com/eddyerburgh/jest-transform-stub).

> In your Jest config, add jest-transform-stub to transform non JavaScript assets you want to stub:
>
> ```js
> {
>   "jest": {
>     // ..
>     "transform": {
>       "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
>       ".+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$": "jest-transform-stub"
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> ### FAQ
>
> **My module isn't being transformed**
>
> Jest doesn't apply transforms to node_modules by default. You can solve this by using `moduleNameMapper`:
>
> ```js
> {
>   "jest": {
>     // ..
>     "moduleNameMapper": {
>       "^.+.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$": "jest-transform-stub"
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: Solved it for me!

Answer (score 1):

I've solved same problem with ignore-styles(https://github.com/bkonkle/ignore-styles). I've used this lib with mocha but I think it should be ok with jest.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Tried it as outlined in the readme, but no success.

Answer (score 0):

A method I'm using for several years without noticing any problems is via the [identity-obj-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/identity-obj-proxy) package:

```
  moduleNameMapper: {
    // Use proxy to mock CSS Modules. Lookups on the styles object will be returned as-is
    // (e.g. styles.foobar === 'foobar')
    '\\.(css|scss|less)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
  },
```

It's somewhat similar to the `jest-transform-stub` method (outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55853617/8555393)) but has a benefit of actually displaying something meaningful - there is [a nice example](https://github.com/keyz/identity-obj-proxy#readme) on the package's GitHub readme how that does look like in praxis (in a snapshot).